# right join query return non-matching values

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am trying to optimize a query and I have it down to something like this,

```
select a.* from 
(select id, count(oid) as cnt from stuff1 s1 inner join stuff2 s2 on s1.id=s2.id group by id) as a
right join
(select id,'0' as cnt from stuff2) as b
on a.id = b.id
```

Basically the goal was to get the count for each oid, where those having 0 count are also included.  I had a query previous to this that worked fine but it took 30 seconds to execute.  I am looking to optimize the old query with this one, but I am getting NULL values from table b.  I need the values from table b to show up with id and 0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An example of the data set could be,

Stuff1

```
| oid | id |
|---- |----|
| 1   | 1  |
| 2   | 1  |
| 3   | 2  |
| 4   | 3  |
```

Stuff2

```
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
| 6  |
| 7  |
```

the query should produce

```
| id | cnt |
|----|-----|
| 1  | 2   |
| 2  | 1   |
| 3  | 1   |
| 4  | 0   |
| 5  | 0   |
| 6  | 0   |
| 7  | 0   |
```

Comment: Can you include the tables definition please?

Comment: A sample data set with expected results would also be helpful.

Comment: @JRD I have included a sample with expected results if it helps.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `UNION` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is syntactically incorrect (`oid` may not be defined; `id` in the `select` is ambiguous).  However, I suspect you want a simple `left join`:

```
select s2.id, count(s1.id) as cnt
from stuff2 s2 left join
     stuff1 s1
     on s1.id = s2.id
group by s2.id;
```

Comment: I hope my clarification above explains things a little better.  I tried your query but am not getting NULL results as zero from stuff2.